# We need to filter the records based on lastmodified date for each no (example :DB1902718) but not with cancel status as per example

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft

Input :

```
{
  "files-list": [
    {
      "fileName": "esp/outbound/poacks/b2bi/input/ESP-Load-DB1902717-COMPLETE-20200415155427_115768.xml",
      "fileSize": 2001,
      "lastModified": "2020-04-16T12:26:37"
    },
    {
      "fileName": "esp/outbound/poacks/b2bi/input/ESP-Load-DB1902718-CANCELLED-20200415155427_115768.xml",
      "fileSize": 2001,
      "lastModified": "2020-04-17T12:26:38"
    },
    {
      "fileName": "esp/outbound/poacks/b2bi/input/ESP-Load-DB1902718-COMPLETE-20200415155427_115768.xml",
      "fileSize": 2001,
      "lastModified": "2020-04-16T12:26:35"
    },
    {
      "fileName": "esp/outbound/poacks/b2bi/input/ESP-Load-DB1902719-COMPLETE-20200415155427_115768.xml",
      "fileSize": 2001,
      "lastModified": "2020-04-18T12:26:39"
    },
     {
      "fileName": "esp/outbound/poacks/b2bi/input/ESP-Load-DB1902719-CANCELLED-20200415155427_115768.xml",
      "fileSize": 2001,
      "lastModified": "2020-04-17T12:26:39"
    },
     {
      "fileName": "esp/outbound/poacks/b2bi/input/ESP-Load-DB1902719-COMPLETE-20200415155427_115768.xml",
      "fileSize": 2001,
      "lastModified": "2020-04-16T12:26:39"
    }
  ]
}
```

output:

```
{
  "files-list": [

    {
      "fileName": "esp/outbound/poacks/b2bi/input/ESP-Load-DB1902717-COMPLETE-20200415155427_115768.xml",
      "fileSize": 2001,
      "lastModified": "2020-04-16T12:26:37"
    },
    {
      "fileName": "esp/outbound/poacks/b2bi/input/ESP-Load-DB1902719-COMPLETE-20200415155427_115768.xml",
      "fileSize": 2001,
      "lastModified": "2020-04-18T12:26:39"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have created some dw but unable to get exact result. Please find below which i tried from my end:

```
%dw 2.0 
output application/json 
fun splitByLoadNumber(aString) = ((aString splitBy "/")[5] splitBy "-")[2] 
fun isCancelled(item) = item contains( "CANCELLED" )
var orderedData={ "files-list": payload."files-list" orderBy ((record,index) -> (record.lastModified)) groupBy splitByLoadNumber($.fileName) pluck $ map $[-1] } 
--- 
"files-list":orderedData."files-list"
```

Comment: What is the filter? One date? a range? Why `2020-04-16T12:26:35` was left out of the output? You need to be more clear on what exactly do you need.

Comment: Hi we have multiple filename contains status like completed,canceled,new and many more and we have lastmodified date .My requirement is to get all latest file based on no present is filename  and exclude file if status is canceled.I have created some dw but unable to get exact result.

Comment: please find below which i tried from my end .It need modification   %dw 2.0
output application/json
fun splitByLoadNumber(aString) = ((aString splitBy "/")[5] splitBy "-")[2]
var orderedData={ "files-list": payload."files-list" orderBy ((record,index) -> (record.lastModified)) groupBy splitByLoadNumber($.fileName) pluck $ map $[-1] 

}
---

"files-list":orderedData."files-list"

Comment: DB1902717 is unique and styatus is not canceled so this should come in output
DB1902718 is having 2 recordes and latest one is canceled status as per last modified date so DB1902718 will not coma at all
DB1902719 is having 3 records and latest one is non canceled so latest one based on last modified date should go'so output should be.....please refer output given above..and thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

You were nearly there. You just needed to filter by the status.

Example:

```
%dw 2.0 
output application/json 
fun splitByLoadNumber(aString) = ((aString splitBy "/")[5] splitBy "-")[2] 
fun isCancelled(item) = item contains( "CANCELLED" )
var orderedData={ "files-list": payload."files-list" orderBy ((record,index) -> (record.lastModified)) groupBy splitByLoadNumber($.fileName) pluck $ map $[-1] } 
--- 
"files-list":orderedData."files-list" filter !isCancelled($.fileName)
```

Note that my status check is somewhat naive. I just check the file name for the string CANCELLED. If the file name format is fixed you could do a more strict check, which I recommend.